# Making Factual drake work on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: tools

I have installed [Drake](https://github.com/Factual/drake) on Windows 7 64-bit.

I am using JDK 1.7.0_51.

I tried both using the pre-compiled jar file and
compiling from the Clojure source using [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen).
The resulting Drake version is 0.1.6, the current development version.

When running Drake, I get the current version number.

Next, I tried to go through [the tutorial](https://github.com/Factual/drake/wiki/Tutorial). The command:

```
java -jar drake.jar  -w .\workflow.d
```

results in the following Exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: no input data found in locations: D:\tools\drake\in.c
sv
```

Even though the file exists and has text inside it. 
The same scenario works in a similar installation on Ubuntu 12.04.
Am I doing something wrong, or is this a Windows-specific bug?